# How do we run executions differently in local development machines and in deployment?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I want to use exploded wars (for speed) when developing locally, but create proper zipped wars when deploying to the cloud.

How do I run different executions in each environment?

```
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-war</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>war-exploded</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exploded</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
```

Comment: I think what you need are profiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably rely on Maven profiles (see [introduction to Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)) in order to configure the war plugin into an environment specific profile.

Comment: This link also helps
http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/maven2/m2-execution/configure-default-and-alternative-executions-in-maven-pom-using-profiles